# making a new dataframe by looking for keywords in specific variable

Tags: r, search, export, keyword

I have a big dataset of about 35000 cases X 32 variables
one of those variables is `Description` in which a description of status is given. for example: patient suffered ischemic stroke.

Now I would like to make a dataframe in which I place all cases in which the word "stroke", "STROKE" or "Stroke" is found in the variable `Description`.

Could anyone suggest a efficient way to do this. Because now I just added all by hand in a very inefficient way:

```
df1<-rbind(df[1,],df[2,],df[3,]
```

It works but it's unbelievably inelegant and prone to mistakes.

Comment: `df1 <- df[grep("(?i)stroke", df$Description), 1:3]`?

Comment: @lukeA works perfectly

Comment: @lukeA now i'm looking for problems with the kidneys, but i do not want to include people with cancer: this is what i have now

     df1<-df[grep("(?i)kidney|(?i)renal", df$description),]

this gives me 200 results of which 30 are about cancer, determined by

     dfC<-df1[grep("(?i)cancer", df1$description),]

This does not work

                             df1<-df[grep("(?i)kidney|(?i)renal & !(?i)cancer", df$description),]

suggestion for this?

Comment: I'd say `df1<-df[grepl("kidney|renal", df$description, ignore.case=T) & !grepl("cancer", df$description, ignore.case=T),] `.

Comment: Works again.. but why doesn't grep work anymore and grepl does?

Comment: `grep` works, too. However you have to apply it differently. `grepl` returns a logical/boolean vector (`TRUE`/`FALSE` values), whereas `grep` returns the matching (or non matching with the parameter `invert = TRUE`) row numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here I create some example data to work with.

```
a <- c(1:10)    
b <- c(11:20)
description  <-  c("Stroke","ALS","Parkinsons","STROKE","STROKE","stroke","Alzheimers","Stroke","ALS","Parkinsons")
df<-data.frame(a,b,description)
df
    a  b description
1   1 11      Stroke
2   2 12         ALS
3   3 13  Parkinsons
4   4 14      STROKE
5   5 15      STROKE
6   6 16      stroke
7   7 17  Alzheimers
8   8 18      Stroke
9   9 19         ALS
10 10 20  Parkinsons
```

With this code you can remove every case (row) that is not associated with "Stroke", "STROKE" or "stroke":

```
df1<-df[!(df$description!="STROKE" & df$description!="Stroke" & df$description!="stroke"),]
df1
  a  b description
1 1 11      Stroke
4 4 14      STROKE
5 5 15      STROKE
6 6 16      stroke
8 8 18      Stroke
```

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: You could also call tolower on Description, which puts all words in lower case, and simplify Olli J's answer to a positive df1 <- df[df$description == "stroke"), ]